# English UI Terminology: Directory, or Folder?

Tags: user-interface

When you are designing an application (assumed in English), and you ask the user to provide a path to a directory/folder, do you use the term **Directory** or **Folder**?

Is one more understood than the other? Is one more "correct" than the other?

Comment: Btw, some better answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078676/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directory-and-a-folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience, these tend to be the norm:

> on Windows or any Mac OS: "Folder"
> on *nix: "Directory"

The *correctness* of the term is wrapped up in how much your application behaves and talks like other applications on the platform, so it is best to stick with convention as to not confuse your users.

---

On the other hand, if the term needs to be cross-platform:

- We can always use the `Folder` term,
- because even if we use the term `Folder` in Linux-based platforms,
- anyone knowing the technical-difference
  ([mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195096/8740349))
  between `Folder` and `Directory` would understand that `Directory` was meant.

  > For example, in `MacOS` we use `Folder` term, while they are technically-speaking directories.

Comment: It's "folder" only on modern Windows Versions like 95 and above.

Comment: @Jules I hardly consider a 15 year old OS (at the time your comment was posted) "modern".

Comment: ;) (should've followed my original comment, but I assumed it's implicit). Just wanted to point out, that the norm changed then. In fact, when you use the commandline on any Windows, you'll still encounter <DIR>.

Comment: @mafu It's so misleading and incorrect that you won't even tell us in which way!

Answer (score 15):

Please note that they are *not* synonyms. Directories and Folders behave differently. For example, if you want to remove a File from a Folder, you need access to the Folder *and* the File, because the File is *stored* inside the Folder.

If, however, you want to remove a File from a Directory, you need access *only* to the Directory, because a Directory itself is just a regular File that lists the *locations* of (but does not *contain*) other Files. So, you just need to strike out that entry from the Directory, no access to the File is required.

This distinction is pretty important, because false and thus misleading metaphors can be at least confusing and in the worst case pretty dangerous when talking about filesystems. (Confusion about filesystem behaviour often translates into accidental information disclosure, data loss or security holes.)

A great percentage of questions on Unix mailinglists, but also here, on ServerFault and on SuperUser, about what to the asker *seems* to be confusing filesystem behaviour, can be traced directly back to thinking about Folders, when Unix does in fact have Directories.

So, in other words: use "Folder" when dealing with folders and "Directory" when dealing with directories.

Comment: Well... *you* as the developer perhaps need to know the distinction, but average Joe really doesn't. I think he needs to see whatever term will make it through his thick skull even if it isn't quite correct.

Comment: In my experience, it is *especially* the average Joe that gets confused by wrong metaphors. In fact, developers don't *need* metaphors, if they want to know how a POSIX filesystem works, they read the spec. I can only repeat: I have seen average users that have lost data or accidentally disclosed private information, because someone had told them that /home/joeuser was a folder, when, in fact, it is a directory.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Right. If only someone had told her that `/home/peoplecallmejustgrandma` was a *directory*, and not a *folder*, then everything would have been much, much different.

Comment: is this actually the case for Windows? You can remove something from a directory but it still exist in other directories and the general file system? I thought there was essentially no difference because the definition of the 'folder' structure was the MFT so there are no independent directories as such. Just the single master record of relationships between disk space, files and a directory/folder/parent whatever structure. I suppose the ultimate thing to remember is that never does either term mean one contains the other in a literal 'space' sense - they are always purely as references.

Comment: I don't think "Folder" has a well defined meaning on any UNIX systems I've used, and I've never seen a system that has the access semantics you discuss in this answer.  (In my experience, "directory" is used at the command line; "Folder" is used in GUIs.)

Answer (score 4):

'Directory' is older and usually used on Unix-ish systems. 'Folder' is usually used on Windows. Personally, I use 'folder' even for GUI apps on both Linux and Windows, it just sounds more "user friendly". (And I doubt anyone will really care that I didn't use the "correct" term.)

If you think your users (e.g. technical users) will be happier with 'directory', use that, but otherwise, I would go with 'folder'.

Answer (score 3):

Use whatever the target OS/DE uses. This definitely means "folder" on Win32, not sure about other platforms (though I think it is also definitely "folder" on OS X, and uncertain on Unix-likes). What you want is for your application to use the same terminology as all other apps, and system dialogs.

It also depends on the type of the application. For command-line applications, "directory" rather than "folder" seems to be the norm everywhere (including Win32).

Answer (score 0):

The term Folder has been primary used by windows systems to make a better association to document-organization and is, as others said just another term. If you won't serve different terms for different systems, use the term Directory.