# Bash script to organize files based on their name

Tags: regex, bash

I need help getting a bash script set up to move files to folders based on the beginning of their name (up til the first .), so for example:

- aaa.123.txt
- aaa.124.txt
- aaa.156.txt
- aaa.122.txt
- bbb.1424.txt
- bbb.13.txt
- bbb.13.txt
- ccc.222.txt

this would generate the following folders, with the appropriate text files inside

- aaa/

  - aaa.123.txt
  - aaa.124.txt
  - aaa.156.txt
  - aaa.122.txt
- bbb/

  - bbb.1424.txt
  - bbb.13.txt
  - bbb.13.txt
- ccc/

  - ccc.222.txt

Comment: `for i in *.*.txt; do d=${i%%.*}; mkdir -p "$d"; mv "$i" "$d"; done`  This won't create any folders for you, but you probably meant to say "directories".

Comment: @WilliamPursell making difference between the terms *folder* and *directory* is unnecessary and just confusing - whats the impact of this?

Comment: @alecxs I disagree. Folders are an artifact of the gui. In the physical world, folders contain files. Directories do not. The belief that directories contain files is one of the common fundamental misunderstandings.

Comment: whats the impact of this wrong belief? i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078676/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directory-and-a-folder) and still don't get it, there is no benefit of that kind of knowledge

Comment: "no benefit"!?  Seriously?  You dont see the benefit of understanding how the filesystem works?  You dont see the harm of misunderstanding it?  Look at iTunes and observe the phenomenal waste of disk resources caused by its pandering to this misunderstanding.  The ability to work with files is one of the core purposes of a computer.  Not understanding how that system works leads to inefficient, inelegant solutions. The word "folder" was introduced by marketing and has no place in a technical discussion that isnt about a gui.

Comment: we are talking about folders and directories (not files) 
right? unless you can tell alternative cmd like `mkdir` (but for creating folders) i can't see whats the problem in mixing up terms. if i want to create a folder but in real i do make a directory and i don't even know that this not what i believe, that makes absolutely no difference

Comment: funny thing is i don't even know how to create a *"folder"* or a *"subfolder"* (because i can just create directories with `mkdir`). so iTunes waste disk resources caused by misunderstanding folders and directories? is there any example for inefficient inelegant solution with folders instead of directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
MYDIR="${PWD}";

for FLE in ${MYDIR}/*.txt;
do
FNAME=$(echo $(basename ${FLE}) | cut -d "." -f 1);

mkdir ${FNAME};

mv ${FLE} ${FNAME};

done
```

Change `${PWD}` to whatever the path should be. Or just execute the script from the directory where the files are.

Comment: *Change ${PWD} to whatever the path should be.* except path with spaces